# Google Analytics and ECSlidingViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, viewcontroller

how can i use Google Analytics and ECSlidingViewController in my iOS App?

Google Analytics does not start when the first ViewController is an ECSlidingViewController...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to make sure your RootViewController is Subclass of GAITrackedViewController

so:

```
ECSSlidingViewController : GAITrackedViewController
```

then you can get your tracker Via

```
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
```

and do as you wish.

Maybe Something Like -

```
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"My Screen"];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
[[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];
```

**I just noticed this question if from April so you probably solved this ages ago!

Enjoy!